# How can I remove event handler?

Tags: c#, silverlight

/

```
/First Version        
public Sniper(string sourceTableName, ComboBox targetComboBox)
{
    proxy.GetBasicEntryAsync(sourceTableName);
    proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted += GetBasicEntryCompleted;
}
void GetBasicEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted -= OnBasicEntryCompleted;

    if (e.Result.Any())
    {
        targetComboBox.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
        targetComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
        targetComboBox.SelectedItem = "ID";
    }
    else
    {
        targetComboBox.ItemsSource = null;
    }
}
```

The HTML object element is compatible with all supported Web browsers, and provides the basis for the Silverlight.js embedding technique. The Silverlight.js embedding functions ultimately generate HTML object elements, and expose all the features that the object element exposes. This common basis enables you to combine both embedding techniques.

```
>     //Second Version
    >     public Sniper(string sourceTableName, ComboBox targetComboBox)
    >     {
    >         proxy.GetBasicEntryAsync(sourceTableName);
    >         proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted += (sender, e) => //This the event
    >         {
    >             //  proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted -= OnBasicEntryCompleted; I want to perform this action in this lambda expression.
    >             if (e.Result.Any())
    >             {
    >                 targetComboBox.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
    >                 targetComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
    >                 targetComboBox.SelectedItem = "ID";
    >             }
    >             else
    >             {
    >                 targetComboBox.ItemsSource = null;
    >             }
    >         };

>     }
```

Comment: your question is not understandable.

Comment: There is a delete key on your keyboard, if this is not what you wanted then you should try to *describe* your problem

Comment: sorry guys - the question is rather clear - @NEO you cannot remove an annon. handler like this - you have to give it some name

Comment: @CarstenKönig - For future readers, this question is very unclear without actually taking the time to decipher it. It is the OP's responsibility to make sure that their question doesn't need to be deciphered

Comment: no we can all help new members - that's why you can edit questions - and it is all in the title - there is only one event handler in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give your handler a name first and save the unsubscribtion somewhere (for example a Action on the base-class - you might prefer a `IDisposable` too but sadly there are no ann. interface-implementations like this in C#, so I go with the Action):

```
private Action _removeSubs;

public Sniper(string sourceTableName, ComboBox targetComboBox)
    {
        proxy.GetBasicEntryAsync(sourceTableName);
        Action <object, EventArgs> _handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Result.Any())
            {
                targetComboBox.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
                targetComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
                targetComboBox.SelectedItem = "ID";
            }
            else
            {
                targetComboBox.ItemsSource = null;
            }
        };
        proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted += handler;
        _removeSubs = () => proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted -= handler;
    }
```

then if you can remove it like this:

```
_removeSubs();
```

BTW: your `proxy` seems to be global or local to the class - so you can just store the Handler/Action too.

The Methoad approach Oliver mentioned works in this case as well, but as you need the `targetComboBox` inside your hander you would need to capture/store this somehwere - this is why I would recommend the *local* approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove anonymous lambdas event handlers. Instead put your lambda into a normal method. Than you can call `proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted -= MyMethod;`.

Here is an example how it could look like:

```
private void OnBasicEntryCompleted(object sender, BasicEntryEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Any())
    {
        e.TargetComboBox.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
        e.TargetComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
        e.TargetComboBox.SelectedItem = "ID";
    }
    else
    {
        e.TargetComboBox.ItemsSource = null;
    }

    var proxy = (Proxy)sender;

    proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted -= OnBasicEntryCompleted;
}

public void Sniper(string sourceTableName, ComboBox targetComboBox)
{
    proxy.GetBasicEntryCompleted += OnBasicEntryCompleted;
    proxy.GetBasicEntryAsync(sourceTableName, targetComboBox);
}
```

Also be aware that you always subscribe to an event BEFORE you invoke the method that will raise it. Otherwise it could happen, that won't be informed due to a racing condition.

And if you call this async method the question would be in which thread will the completed event be raised? If it happens in thread where the async task had run, you won't be within the gui thread and manipulating gui objects (like the combo box) is not recommended within other threads. So maybe encapsulate your accesses to the combo box within a `e.TargetComboBox.Invoke()` call.